# Отсортировать пузырьком двумерный динамический массив

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

изучаю c++ недавно и в руки попала задача. Задать матрицу n порядка и отсортировать ее пузырьком. После создания и заполнения случайными числами идет сортировка и в этот момент консоль останавливает работу с кодом -1073741819. Буду очень благодарен любой помощи.

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    cout << "Введите размер матрицы: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int m = n;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int **arr = new int*[m];// динамический массив с случайными числами
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) arr[i] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 110;
        }
    }
    cout << "Матрица:" << endl;//вывод матрицы
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int temp; // Сортировка
    for (int k = 0; k < m * n; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
                if (arr[k][j] > arr[k][j + 1]) {
                    temp = arr[k][j];
                    arr[k][j] = arr[k][j + 1];
                    arr[k][j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Матрица после сортировки:" << endl;//вывод матрицы
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i(0); i < m; i++) delete arr[i];//удаление динамического массива из оперативной памяти
    delete [] arr;
    return 0;
} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, создаем матрицу...

```
int **arr = new int*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) arr[i] = new int[n];
```

Размером `m*n`. По сути `n*n`. С первой размерностью `n`.

И как мы с ней работаем?

```
for (int k = 0; k < m * n; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[k][j] > arr[k][j + 1]) {
```

Т.е. обращаемся, например, к элементу `arr[m*n-1][j]`. Но первая размерность, как уже сказано, равна `n`. И если только `n` не равно 1, то получается выход за пределы массива. И очень далекий выход :)

Результат очевиден...

Comment: Можете подсказать как это исправить? Я понял в чем ошибка, но как код исправить пока не дошло.